# ¿Cómo puedo pasar un return dentro del valor de una directiva v-on?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

En Javascript para retornar un valor dentro del valor de un evento se hace de la siguiente forma:

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)">
```

Cosa que no puedo realizar en Vue, ya que me devuelve error:

```html
<input type="text" v-on:keypress="return soloNumeros($event)">
<!--Failed to compile.
...
Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/templateLoader.js):-->
```

¿Cuál sería la forma de ejecutar dicha función en el Framework de Vue?, gracias de antemano.

Comment: De forma coloquial: No se usa esa practica en vue, a diferencia use los métodos (``methods:{}``)